# How to post data in angular

Tags: php, angular, typescript

This is the angular code i used to post data

```
  const postData = {
        "username": "Customer004",
        "email": "customer004@email.com",
        "password": "0000252525",
        "gender": "male",
    }

    this.http.post("http://localhost/android/Api.php?apicall=signup", postData, options)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

But when i tried to print the response i am getting null in the backend using php code

```
response['post']=$_POST['username'];
```

it is giving me `null` value

this is my php code..
I have hardcoded the data.But trying to print post request.It is giving me null
This is my php code
https://pastebin.com/raw/VishzAvG
My angular code is here

https://pastebin.com/raw/LNk3KvYW

Comment: see network tab that either your browser is making `http post` or not? and if it is making the `post` request so please see `payload` in your request

Comment: Validate your API first using postman or CURL. Ensure it is working fine.

Comment: @Arcteezy I checked it with postman .It works fine.I think the problem is passing post data using angular

Comment: {error: true, message: "User already registered", post: null}
error: true
message: "User already registered"
post: null

Comment: @Fahad Hassan .I am getting null in network tab.

Comment: So you are trying to add existing user that's why your api sending you error response. Try with another user to singup and then please post screenshot of network tab request details(payload)

Comment: You are getting an error and not a proper response which is not handled properly. Try with another user like @FahadHassan suggested and see if you get proper response.

Comment: @Arcteezy.I have added some more details can you please help me

Comment: @FahadHassan .I have added some more details can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

At the backend in php use

```
   $post=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
   echo $post->username;
```

It'll work

Comment: const postData = {
        "username": "Customer004",
        "email": "customer004@email.com",
        "password": "0000252525",
        "gender": "male",
    }

This is the json that is passed how to get username in backend.This json is passed from a hybrid app

Comment: what to give in php://input. I am posting json data from a client which is a mobile app

Comment: Because post is an input to php, it'll do what you are trying.

Comment: let me try 1 sec